# Exiting from vi

Tags: raspbian

This kind of thing is sooo frustrating.  Following these [instructions to install Edimax](http://www.frodebang.com/post/how-to-install-the-edimax-ew-7811un-wifi-adapter-on-the-raspberry-pi) wifi dongle, and I'm stuck at 'configure wireless network connection'. The command `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces` opens the file in a viewer, either in the GUI or from command line.  But there are no instructions for how to edit/save/exit and anything you enter seems to change the file. The only way to ecxit is to pull the power plug and afterwards the pi fails to load - it just rotates endelssly through the installation sequence - requiring a fresh installation.  I've had to reinstall twice now because of this.

So please:
1. are there any instructions for the vi app?  For instance [this guide](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html) makes no mention.
2. is there any way to undo changes in vi?

Comment: please look at this cheat sheet. http://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vi` -- or at, least, the "improved" version, `vim` -- is a great piece of software, but it is not easy to use, and the default configuration, which does not indicate the difference between *insert* and *command* modes, is awkward (the basic philosophy is that features are not enabled, making it seem pretty "featureless").

I totally encourage you to learn vim at some point, if it holds some appeal for you.  However, what I don't recommend is trying to hack-use it while you are also trying to do some other thing for the first time -- as you observe, this will probably be a very frustrating, "WTF?" laden experience.

A lot of linux/unix instructions include references to vi because it is required software on such systems, so it is guaranteed to be there.  Some stuff replaces this with `nano`, which is not required, and therefore might not be available, but it is a much much simpler beast than `vi` and should be easy; the `^X` `^G` functions at the bottom mean "ctrl-X", "ctrl-G", etc, and one of them is a help.

I think nano is included in the base raspbian but if not, just `apt-get install nano`.  Then you can just use `nano` instead of `vi` for simple tasks like this.

WRT "are there any instructions for the vi app" -- yes, there are entire books on it, and a built-in help feature with plenty of available reading.  I recommend you add this to the top of `~/.vimrc`

```
set nocp
```

And try `vimtutor`.  If that's what you really want to do ;).

To just exit, hit `esc` then type `:q!`.

Comment: Thanks goldilocks this is this kind of useful guidance I wish I'd read sooner!